# Movement in cartodb

Tags: carto, line

I have a DB with the history of the movement of a migrancy family. I would like to display these movement. How can i do?

this is a good example [my target](https://cartodb.com/gallery/updated-movement/)

Comment: Could you add more information about the data that you have? Is it points, is it polygons? Does it contain timestamps?

Comment: The data are points and I have coordinates and timestamps

Answer (score 1):

This [Animated maps with point data](https://academy.cartodb.com/courses/beginners-course/animated-maps-with-point-data/) tutorial should be a good starting point for you. In general taking a careful look on the tutorials available on the academy is a good idea to start working with CartoDB.